# Marking item as "Delivery not met" sharepoint list

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, sharepoint-list, status

New to SharePoint lists.. trying to find a way to mark items that did not meet the deadline.

I have the column "Expected Completion Date" and "Date of Completion" (Both are in mm/dd/yyyy format). I want to have another column that says "Commitment Met" and if the date of completion is before or on the expected completion date, it will say "Met." If it was completed after the expected completion date, it will say "Not Met"

Finally, for items that are in progress / haven't been closed out yet so only Expected Completion Date is filled in - I would like it to remain blank or have a "-"

It doesn't work in SharePoint but something like:

IF("Date of Completion" < "Expected Completion Date", "Met"), IF("Date of Completion Date" > "Expected Completion Date", "Not Met");

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it? First we check if `Date of Completion` is blank (not set) and return a "-" for that.

Next, we check if it is less than the expected date and set it to "Met",

Finally a check for "Not Met" and then a "-" again for if all the IF tests fail...

```
=IF([Date of Completion]="","-",IF(
[Date of Completion]<[Expected Completion Date],"Met",IF([Date of Completion]>[Expected Completion Date],"Not Met","-")))
```